# Not able to copy data from many table and insert into one table using hibernate query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am trying to copy data from many table and store into one table using **hibernate** query.

Below is my code:

```
Query query=session.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT m.subs_id, m.email_id 
         FROM SubcriberModel m  
         WHERE m.subs_id IS NOT NULL  
         AND m.email_id IS NOT NULL  
         AND m.email_id <> ''  
         UNION ALL "+"
         SELECT DISTINCT t.tbl_subscribers_subs_id, t.email_id  
         FROM SocialProfileModel t 
         WHERE t.tbl_subscribers_subs_id IS NOT NULL  
         AND t.email_id IS NOT NULL 
         AND t.email_id <> ''"); 

int res = query.executeUpdate();
```

In above case,only first select query is getting executed and successfully fetch the data.

I want to **`union`** all data from all select queries. When i executed the above query on Database ,it fetched the data successfully.

Comment: Are you using HQL? 
if you are not rembember uses nativeQuery like :     
Query q = session.createNativeQuery(....

Comment: UNION is not supported in hibernate. You can use native SQL query though

Answer (score 0):

Use Database view, you can use same class for mapping, another option is nativeQuery